# Error in using rgbdslam with GUI

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to implement SLAM using rgbdslam. But when i run the command   "roslaunch rgbdslam kinect+rgbdslam.launch" from the wiki page "http://wiki.ros.org/rgbdslam?distro=fuerte", i get the following error. I appreciate any help.

> WARNING:
> [/home/morteza/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/launch/kinect+rgbdslam.launch]
> unknown  attribute
> 'no_launch-prefix'
>
> [ERROR] [1419625375.970080106]: Tried
> to advertise a service that is already
> advertised in this node
> [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressedDepth/set_parameters]
> [ERROR] [1419625375.977429410]: Tried
> to advertise a service that is already
> advertised in this node
> [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressed/set_parameters]
> [ERROR] [1419625375.988461110]: Tried
> to advertise a service that is already
> advertised in this node
> [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/theora/set_parameters]
>
> REQUIRED process [rgbdslam-23] has
> died! process has died [pid 5256, exit
> code 127, cmd
> /home/morteza/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/bin/rgbdslam
> __name:=rgbdslam __log:=/home/morteza/.ros/log/f811358e-8d3c-11e4-abdb-08edb96bfa77/rgbdslam-23.log].
> log file:
> /home/morteza/.ros/log/f811358e-8d3c-11e4-abdb-08edb96bfa77/rgbdslam-23*.log
> Initiating shutdown!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200094/error-in-using-rgbdslam-with-gui/) by [Morteza](https://answers.ros.org/users/20070/morteza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2014-12-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Morteza](https://answers.ros.org/users/20070/morteza/) on 2014-12-27**:
Also, when i try to start the openni nodes and RGBDSLAM separately with the commands
'roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch'  and 'rosrun rgbdslam rgbdslam', I get the following error.

/home/morteza/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/bin/rgbdslam: error while loading shared libraries: libsiftgpu.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

the first ERROR messages are unrelated, they are from the camera driver and AFAIK can be safely ignored.

The message starting with REQUIRED more or less says that rgbdslam crashed. The message in your comment hints towards a missing library. Apparently you need to build the siftgpu library, which should have been done by rosmake.
To do it manually, run make in `rgbdslam/external/siftgpu/linux` and copy the created `external/siftgpu/linux/bin/libsiftgpu.so` to a directory searched by the linker (try rgbdslam/lib or check the linker command line with `make VERBOSE=1` for `-L/some/dir` parameters).

Also note that there's a much better version available for ROS hydro on [github](http://felixendres.github.io/rgbdslam_v2)

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2015-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Morteza](https://answers.ros.org/users/20070/morteza/) on 2015-01-13**:
Thank you for your response. I downloaded the hydro version and it works well. In fuerte i did what you said but when i ran make, although the libsiftgpu.so was made, i got error.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2015-01-14**:
Ok, I guess that's fine then.